# Как понять принципы разработки ПО?

Tags: java, книги

Доброго всем дня\ночи! Прошу помощи у более опытных коллег. Я изучаю `Java` где-то 6 мес. Заинтересовался разработкой под `Android`, но не в этом суть. Проблема в том, что когда смотрю в книгу или на чужой код программы, мне всё понятно и легко. Когда хочу выполнить сам что-либо, даже что-то простое, не могу понять за что браться и как это сделать. Знакомые люди мне сказали, что у меня плохо с алгоритмами и посоветовали почитать Кнута и Седжавика. Я скачал и почитал, Кнута страниц 100 и у меня уже мозг вывернуло, это ж полный математический бред пьяного ёжика, Седжавик про графы написал 300 страниц, для чего мне эти графы.
Короче, дайте мне какой-либо нормальный ресурс\книгу как "въехать" в разработку ПО ... без заумного математического бреда!

Comment: > я скачал и почитал, Кнута страниц 100 и у меня уже мозг вывернуло, это ж полный математический бред пьяного ёжика

бред - это то, что у вас в голове, а Кнут - это один из лучших теоретиков в области программирования, и если вы его не осилили, то это еще не повод оскорблять выдающегося и заслуженного человека своими бестолковыми шутками

Comment: где то с 150-200 страницы у Кнута начинается занимательное чтиво. Местами там есть очень хитрые выкладки, но при первом чтении их можно аккуратно пропустить по диагонали. Все равно потом будете ещё раз читать.

Comment: С таким подходом -- а зачем вам? Поступайте в менеджеры, и думать не надо, и денег побольше платят.

Comment: >Поступайте в менеджеры, и думать не надо, и денег побольше платят

не дай бог. И так полстраны - "эффективные менеджеры"

Comment: Кнут плох тем, что при чрезмерной сложности языка в его книге сообщаются какие-то тривиальные вещи, что-то на уровне матшкольнкиа из 57-й школы. Критику кнута можно прочитать в блоге профессионального математика: http://heller.ru/blog/2013/02/concrete-mathematics-khuth/

Comment: Там же и альтернативы Кнуту указаны в комментах.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По правде говоря, с солидарен с Алексеем - Кнут заумен, он слишком математичен, для него программирование это разновидность математики. Конечно, людям с мат.образованием или мышлением это в самый раз, но не все увы такие же математики, как я :)

Вообще лучший способ научиться программировать - это программировать, чтение книг здесь не сильно поможет, пока не начнете программировать.

Поставьте себе задачу и начинайте ее реализовывать. Классическая задача это написание калькулятора. Я когда учил Pascal писал калькулятор, учил С писал калькулятор, учил С++ писал калькулятор, когда учил Java писал калькулятор, учил шарпы, писал калькулятор.

Сходите в ближайший магазин канцтоваров, купите себе простенький калькулятор Citizen и начинайте ее реализовывать на Java. По ходу дела все приложится.

Удачи.

Comment: @Barmaley, +мульон :) Помнится, первый калькулятор мы всей толпой человек из 6 писали ещё на СМ 1800, задача казалась трындец какая сложная. И всё равно иногда к ней возвращаюсь.

Comment: А че за зверь СМ-1800? СМ-1420 помню, а 1800 уже нет...

Comment: когда только учился сколько раз брался переписывать что-то столько же раз получалось что-то другое. хотелось бы от себя добавить к ответу что пожалуй самое важно в таком варианте развития это все таки дописать все калькуляторы которые вы начинали писать :)

Comment: [СМ-1800](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%9C_%D0%AD%D0%92%D0%9C) - это  8-разрядная на процессоре КР580ВМ80А (клон Intel 8080)

Comment: @avp, да нам тогда было пофиг калькулятор. клингон атакует - вот это было задачей :)

Comment: Да на программистов-теоретиков сцут как профессиональные математики, для которых Конкретная математика выглядит как ковыряние неосиляторов алгебраической геометрии в испражнениях мамонта, так и профессиональные программисты, которые прочитали про сложность алгоритмов на вики, нарешали десятки олимпиадок и зарабатывают по 100к в отличие от диванных теоретиков, которые жуют локти с солью.

Answer (score 2):

Без "Заумного математического бреда" у вас вряд ли получится в разработке уйти куда то дальше, чем разработка Hello World со свистелками и перделками. Первые 227 страниц Сенджвика 4 издания книги "Алгоритмы на Java" посвящены основам программирования, которые вполне доступно описывают особенности языка и на примерах учат простым вещам. То, что в этой книге есть 300 страниц про графы, еще не значит что она не сможет помочт вам "въехать" в разработку ПО, до этих странниц еще надо дойти.
А вообще такой вам совет: если решили всерьез заняться разработкой ПО, будьте готовы к трудностям, и начинайте понимать математические алгоритмы уже сейчас.

Comment: Тем не менее Кнут тяжеловат для неподготовленного человека. Это уже пускай будет второй этап. А первый этап - начать с хеллоувордлов и калькуляторов, много практиковаться. Без этого умение разбивать задачу на части и реализовывать их, боюсь, будет тяжело получить. А потом можно подтянуть и математику. ИМХО.

Comment: Советую ознакомиться с критикой Кнута: http://heller.ru/blog/2010/08/on-donald-knuths-books/

Answer (score 0):

По алгоритмам мой совет "Алгоритмы построение и анализ." - Кормен.

А по поводу математики. То здесь всё зависит от того в каком направлении хотите работать.
Если нужно 3D графикой заниматься, то придется её изучать.
Если кнопочки и окошечки двигать в web, то нужна арифметика.
Раньше программирование было прочно связано с математикой, но с развитием прикладной науки отделилось от неё.

Вообще сам вопрос:

1. Неполный. Конкретней про область. Также какие цели.
2. Разработака ПО - это отдельная концепция включающая множество подзадач

http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Вы имеете ввиду процесс кодирования или разработку архитектуры?
Или ничего из этого?

Comment: Спасибо, уже скачал Кормена. Я хочу быть просто хорошим разработчиком ПО под Android.